# customizing omniauth gem pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I use `omniath-identity gem` for authentication system. I add gem to Gemfile. also I set `omniauth.rb` file for omniauth configuration.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity
end
```

I browse the below link.

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/identity
```

it shows me login page of omniauth-identity. I want to create my own cstom login page. I don't want to see omniauth's login page. how can I remove or change this page and how can I add my custom login page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice railcasts about using omniauth-identity, you should check it on http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity?view=asciicast

But in few words, in order to overwrite the login page, you need to create a controller named **identities**

```
rails g controller identities
```

The content will be something like

```
class IdentitiesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @identity = env['omniauth.identity']
  end
end
```

and then you can create a custom view

```
<h1>New Account</h1>

<%= form_tag "/auth/identity/register" do %>
  <% if @identity && @identity.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@identity.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this account from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @identity.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :name %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, @identity.try(:name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, @identity.try(:email) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= password_field_tag :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Register" %></div>
<% end %>
```

just check the railcast video, everything is there

Comment: thanks for reply. i also want to ask one more question. i read the article you said. we use two controller: identities and sessions. i only use identity provider on my project. can i manage omniauth without using sessions controller. So, can i use create action of identities_controller instead of sessions_controller?

Comment: you can overwrite all the behavior of the identities controller, just remember to update the routes.rb file as described on the article for the identities controller (otherwise it will route to the controller that came with the gem). if this solve your problem/question, I would appreciate a positive vote on my answer and if you can mark the answer as accepted, that build my rating and helps me to get better contracts, thx.